# return to and go back to something

Tags: idiomatic-language

I’m texting my friend saying “*I’m going back to Russell during this wintertime.*” What I wanted to suggest is that I started reading Russell’s work again, is it idiomatic to say that? Are there any better ways to express? Can I also say something like *I returned to Russell?*

Comment: You can confirm that this usage is theoretically possible by reading Cambridge's dictionary entries (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/return). However, it's true that this leads to misunderstandings because a physical location is expected when using these. If you want a more idiomatic expression you could say "I am picking up Russell's books again this wintertime", as this explicitly makes a reference to books. Nevertheless, if the other speaker is aware of the context, then it should not raise any issues.

Comment: If you really do want to use this expression you may explicitly use a verb to distinguish it from a physical place, i.e., "I'm going back to reading Russell during this wintertime".

Comment: It's fine if your friend already knows that you read a lot of Russell's work at some time in the past.

Comment: "I'm going back to Russell ..." or "I'm returning to Russell ..." are equally idiomatic, although as others have said, they would need context to make the meaning clear. I assumed Russell was a place until I read your explanation. Also, "during this wintertime" is not idiomatic. Just "this winter" works much better here.

Comment: What about "revisiting Russell"? This to me at least has less of a connotation of going to a physical place than "going back to" or "returning."